# StructureMap: PluginType and PluggedType in different assemblies

Tags: structuremap

I'm hitting against the wall with this and I can't figure out:

I have the following interfaces:

```
namespace SupplyOrder.Objects.Interfaces
{
    public interface ILoginRepository<T>
    {
         T GetUser(string username, string password);
    }
}

namespace SupplyOrder.Objects.Interfaces
{
    public interface ILoginService
    {
        User GetUser(string username, string password);
    }
}
```

and classes that impelement this interfaces:

Service class:

```
namespace SupplyOrder.Service
{
    public class LoginService : ILoginService
    {
        readonly ILoginRepository<User> _loginRepository;
        public LoginService(ILoginRepository<User> loginRepository)
        {
            _loginRepository = loginRepository;
        }

        public User GetUser(string username, string password)
        {
            return _loginRepository.GetUser(username, password);
        }

    }
}
```

UserRepository class:

```
namespace SupplyOrder.Dal
{
    public class UserRepository : ILoginRepository<User>
    {
        public User GetUser(string username, string password)
        {
            // call to DB
        }
    }
}
```

In Bootstraper.cs file I have this:

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController
        GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext,
        Type controllerType)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((requestContext == null) || (controllerType == null))
                return null;

            return (Controller)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType);
        }
        catch (StructureMapException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave());
            throw new Exception(ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave());
        }
    }
}

public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        ControllerBuilder.Current
            .SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());

        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddConfigurationFromXmlFile("StructureMap.xml");
        });
    }
}
```

StructureMap.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StructureMap>
    <DefaultInstance
        PluginType="SupplyOrder.Objects.Interfaces.ILoginRepository`1, SupplyOrder.Objects"
        PluggedType="SupplyOrder.Dal.UserRepository, SupplyOrder.Dal"
    />

    <DefaultInstance
        PluginType="SupplyOrder.Objects.Interfaces.ILoginService, SupplyOrder.Objects"
        PluggedType="SupplyOrder.Service.LoginService, SupplyOrder.Service"
    />
</StructureMap>
```

When I run my MVC3 website, it gives me this error:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'SupplyOrder.Dal.UserRepository' from     assembly 'SupplyOrder.Dal'.
```

If all classes and interfaces are in the same assembly it works, but I want to have
all this in a structured way.

Thank you for your help,
Jani

Comment: Is SupplyOrder.Dal assembly referenced in your MVC3 application? Is your repository public?

Comment: Yes, SupplyOrder.Dal assembly is referenced in MVC application and repository class is public.